# The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting below error message when I run the application.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAZ0Z.png)

I did a search and tried different solutions.

I opened SQL Server Configuration Manager, SQL Server Network Configuration, protocols for `SQLEXPRESS`, right click on TCP/IP, IP address tab and changed TCP port to 1433. Didn't work.

[SQL Server Configuration Manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEZ4d.png)

In `services.msc`, the SQL Server process (`SQLEXPRESS`) status is running.

Looking for help please.

Thank you.

Comment: Post the *error* not a link to a screenshot of the error. Also *google* for the error message. It says that it can't create an automatic instance. This means you tried to use the `AttachDbFilename` keyword. This only works when SQL Server *Express* is installed locally. What is your connection string? Does it point to a correct path?

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, This is the connection string. I apologize. I am in beginners level with SQL server. Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mr_P\Desktop\LocalDbExample\LocalDbExample\App_Data\ACME.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework. I appreciate your support.

Comment: You are using LocalDB in the connection string however on the post you have stated as its SQLExpress. The LocalDB and sqlexpress is not same and each have its own instance and connection strings.

Comment: @Daigham, Can you please mark the answer as correct so that it will be helpful for the others who is looking out to resolve the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your connection string for the issue. May be the servername or the database you are using might not be correct.

The connection string for entity framework ( i hope you are using this as per your screenshot) has to be in the below format.

```
<add name="<keyname>"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
                       database=YourDatabaseName;
                       AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|<dbname>.mdf;
                       User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Hi, can you mark the answer as correct if it really helped to solve your issue?